# jquery contextMenu + .live

Tags: jquery-plugins, jquery

I am using a plugin called [jQuery contextMenu](http://labs.abeautifulsite.net/projects/js/jquery/contextMenu/demo/) but am having trouble making it work with elements that are loaded via ajax after the DOM has already loaded. does anyone know how i can get this working with .live?

Comment: Where is your code? http://api.jquery.com/live/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've made a modification of the [original jquery.contextMenu.js](http://abeautifulsite.net/blog/2008/09/jquery-context-menu-plugin/) script. I've replaced `.each()` with `.live("mousedown", ...)` and deleted appropriate mousedown binding (you can also make a diff of my code and the original to get the changes).

You can get the code from http://pastebin.com/jBcAR6g1

Works for me.

Answer (score 1):

2018 update without plugin:

```
$(document).on('contextmenu','#object_id',function() {
    //code
});
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you must use [enableContextMenuItems()](http://abeautifulsite.net/blog/2008/09/jquery-context-menu-plugin/#usage) method on the newly added elements. If you post your code it would be easier to help.

Comment: I gave this a shot but it didnt seem to work for me. Thanks for the suggestion. I also tried destroyContextMenu() before enableContextMenuItems() to see if that would make a difference but it did not.

Comment: My code is exactly like the demo except that im generating the div im applying .contextMenu() to via .post(). I can put the demo in jsfiddle if you would like.

Comment: yes, posting an example on jsfiddle always helps getting better answers

Comment: Given the implementation of enableContextMenuItems() it has no rights to run - there's no bind/live call there, only classes modifications.